# usage for MongoDB sort in array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

I would like to ranked in descending order a list of documents in array **names** via their **number** value.

Here's the structure part of my collection :

```
_id: ObjectId("W")
var1: "X",
var2: "Y",
var3: "Z",
comments: {
   names: [
      {
         number: 1;
      },
      {
         number: 3;
      },
      {
         number: 2;
      }
   ],
   field: Y;
}
```

but all my request with `db.collection.find().sort( { "comments.names.number": -1 } )` doesn't work.

the desired output sort is :

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("W"), "var1" : "X", "var3" : "Z", "comments" : { [ { "number" : 3 }, { "number" : 2 },{ "number" : 1 } ], "field": "Y" } }
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to aggregate the result, as below:

- `Unwind` the names array.
- `Sort` the records based on `comments.names.number` in descending
  order.
- `Group` the records based on the `_id` field.
- `project` the required structure.

Code:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind:"$comments.names"},
 {$sort:{"comments.names.number":-1}},
 {$group:{"_id":"$_id",
          "var1":{$first:"$var1"},
          "var2":{$first:"$var2"},
          "var3":{$first:"$var3"},
          "field":{$first:"$comments.field"},
          "names":{$push:"$comments.names"}}},
 {$project:{"comments":{"names":"$names","field":"$field"},"var1":1,
            "var2":1,"var3":1}}  
 ],{"allowDiskUse":true})
```

If your collection is large, you might want to add a `$match` criteria in the beginning of the aggregation pipeline to filter records or use `(allowDiskUse:true)`, to facilitate sorting large number of records.

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
 {$match:{"_id":someId}},
 {$unwind:"$comments.names"},
 {$sort:{"comments.names.number":-1}},
 {$group:{"_id":"$_id",
          "var1":{$first:"$var1"},
          "var2":{$first:"$var2"},
          "var3":{$first:"$var3"},
          "field":{$first:"$comments.field"},
          "names":{$push:"$comments.names"}}},
 {$project:{"comments":{"names":"$names","field":"$field"},"var1":1,
            "var2":1,"var3":1}}  
 ])
```

What The below query does:

```
db.collection.find().sort( { "comments.names.number": -1 } )
```

is to find all the documents, then sort those documents based on the number field in descending order. What this actually does is for each document get the `comments.names.number` field value which is the largest, for each document. And then sort the parent documents based on this number. It doesn't manipulate the names array inside each parent document.

Answer (score 0):

You need update document for sort an array.

```
db.collection.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
       comments.names: {
          $each: [ ],
          $sort: { number: -1 }
       }
     }
   }
)
```

check documentation here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/#use-sort-with-other-push-modifiers

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB queries sort the result documents based on the collection of fields specified in the sort. They do not sort arrays within a document. If you want the array sorted, you need to sort it yourself after you retrieve the document, or store the array in sorted order. See [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655650/how-sort-an-array-in-a-collection) from Stennie.

Comment: This is not true. It is possible using the aggregation framework.