# Updating nested Array elements in mongodb without reputations

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

i have collection called 'test' in that there is a document like:

```
{
"_id" : 1
"letters" : [ 
        [ "A", "B" ], 
        [ "C", "D" ], 
        [ "A", "E", "B", "F" ]
    ]
}
```

if i updated the document by using $addToSet like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"_id" : 1}, {$addToSet:{"letters": ["A", "B"] }})
```

it will not inserted another value. still the document look like

```
{
"_id" : 1
"letters" : [ 
        [ "A", "B" ], 
        [ "C", "D" ], 
        [ "A", "E", "B", "F" ]
    ]
}
```

if im updating like this:

```
db.getCollection('test').update({"_id" : 1}, {$addToSet:{"letters": ["B", "A"] }})
```

Now it will update the document like:

```
{
"_id" : 1
"letters" : [ 
        [ "A", "B" ], 
        [ "C", "D" ], 
        [ "A", "E", "B", "F" ],
        [ "B", "A" ]
    ]
}
```

my requirment is if im give like this also (["B", "A"]), it will not update that document. Because the same letters are already present in the array.

could anyone can please give the solution.

Comment: try to sort your letters before using addToSet

Comment: thx for replying @Shubham. sorting array elements is good idea but database will became slow while using sort(). So can you please tell the solution without sort()

Comment: I am not suggesting using sort on db level just sort your array before updating on app level

Comment: is there any alternative ...? @Shubham

Comment: you can use update({_id:"somethin",letters:{$nin:[['A','B'],['B','A']]}},{$push{letters:['A','B']}})

here [['A','B'],['B','A']] is all possible combinations of ur letters but now this is extremely slow

Comment: There is a good answer regarding a similar question. Read the part about [data modeling considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655650/how-sort-an-array-in-a-collection)  in specific . Data modeling is quite important when you recognize that you need such things and taking mongodb capabilities in consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Shubham has the right answer. You should always sort your letters *before* saving into the document. So your original document should have been (I changed the third array):

```
{
  "_id" : 1,
  "letters" : [ 
        [ "A", "B" ], 
        [ "C", "D" ], 
        [ "A", "B", "C", "F" ]
    ]
}
```

Then in your application do the sort. I'm including a Mongo Shell example here.

```
var input = ["B", "A"];
input.sort();
db.getCollection('test').update({"_id" : 1}, {$addToSet:{"letters":  input}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this answer , it works.

Use $push to insert any item in the array in your case.

```
db.getCollection('stack').update(
       { _id: 1 },
       { $push: { "letters": ["B", "A"] } }
    )
```

For reference about $push you can view this link -

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/